# HTML indexing with solr

Tags: html, solr

I am trying to figure out if its possible to index a segment of html and associate an attribute as metadata to that content with solr. For example:

```
<div class="TODO">Content that needs to be indexed</div>
<div class="FIXME">Fix the broken</div>
```

The content of the above div blocks need to be indexed with the association to the class name of the div block.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do this. Solr does have a HTML stripper that removes all HTML encoding.

You need to parse the segments yourself though.

You can add metadata easily if you create a solr document per segment. Within one document you only have fields to work with, depending on the div's class you'd pick a field to which you add the segment.

Answer (score 0):

to add data to solr have to adapt the format to format solr.

you to transform your xml to solr. you could use XSLT.

Your result should be this.:

```
<add>
  <doc>
    <field name="TODO">Content that needs to be indexed</field>
    <field name="FIXME">Fix the broken</field>
  </doc>
</add>
```

[Here](http://www.xml.com/lpt/a/1668) you can see how to index data in solr xml.

[review this guide of solr.](http://www.solrtutorial.com/solr-in-5-minutes.html)

Comment: Thanks! This is what I would need.